# Is it possible to travel on the Immingham-Brevik ferry without bringing a motor vehicle?

Tags: ferries, norway, england

DFDS Seaways operates [a cargo ferry between Brevik (Norway) and Immingham (England)](http://freight.dfdsseaways.com/DFDS_ferries/North_Sea_ferries/Brevik_Immingham_ferries/).  Apparently, they do take drivers of private cars, for example, see [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/the-freight-escape-simon-calder-left-for-his-skiing-holiday-as-an-airline-passenger-but-came-home-as-cargo-1951914.html).  However, is it possible to book transfer on this ferry when not travelling with any freight?  I don't see this freighter advertised on the usual freighter travel websites.

Comment: @pnuts I saw that link, but it is not obvious to me if those passengers are only considered when accompanying their vehicle, or also when travelling without any freight.

Comment: @pnuts True, I could ask them directly and post the answer here.

Comment: @gerrit any luck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I called the passenger information number in Immingham and spoke with a live agent...

1. Foot passengers who do not have a vehicle will not be permitted to
   board on either side;
2. Passengers on push bikes may be permitted to board in the Immingham,
   unclear for the Brevik side;
3. The entry point in Immingham is covered by the same [Statutory
   Instrument](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2008/5/contents/made) governing airlines, so the [UK Border Force](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/border-force) will be
   alerted from Brevik if they are carrying non-EEA passengers.