# Is there a ferry running from UK to Scandinavia?

Tags: ferries, sea-travel, norway, scotland

I have found [this thread](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/trip-transport/scotland-to-norway-ferry-61524) but it seems to be outdated

[image]

Comment: Last time I searched I did not find any better results than what you find in the answers to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35862/alternative-route-for-the-shut-down-harwich-esbjerg-ferry-route-by-car

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://driveeuropenews.com/2015/01/21/sweden-21/

> The final UK-Scandinavia ferry service, operated by DFDS between Harwich and Esbjerg, Denmark, was withdrawn last September

And

> the start of services – likely between Newcastle, Bergen and Stavanger – the following March

So 2016 March might just see the resumption of ferry service although from Newcastle not Aberdeen.

However http://britishscandinavian.com/ still have nothing firm.

Comment: The British Scandinavian website is down.  I don't believe this service will happen.

Comment: According to the website, they're still working on it, allegedly. I wouldn't hold your breath.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a ferry *per se*, but plenty of cruise ships sail from London Tilbury and Southampton to the Norwegian fjords. Some cruises allow you to only book a part of the journey, so you could use the cruise boat as a fancy ferry. Cruise prices start at around 100 EUR/day and it takes about 36 hours to reach the fjords, so in theory you should be able to pay as little as 200 EUR to get to your destination. Here's [a link](https://us.cruiseandmaritime.com/cruises-501) to one of the companies organizing such cruises.

As a bonus you get to spend your journey in a comfortable boat with plenty amenities.

Comment: But without a car.

Comment: Any link/example?

Comment: @Ulkoma post updated. Not sure how to buy only a part of the cruise, but I've seen people do it when I went on one.

Comment: @Willeke yes but there's plenty of car rentals in Norway. Although I guess you might as well fly then.

Comment: Fred Olsen have a number of cruises to Norway that depart from Newcastle.http://www.fredolsencruises.com/find-your-holiday/cruises-from-newcastle I think that people departing a cruise early just take the money they lose on the chin,

Answer (score 4):

There is a commercial ferry service on DFDS between [Brevik and Immingham](https://www.dfds.com/freight-shipping/routes-and-schedules/brevik-immingham), but they are unable to take private passengers.
I suppose you could hire a van and claim you were on a business trip, but the cost £745 pounds is about the same as you would pay for a cruise like JonathanReez suggests.

Comment: One reason to use a ferry instead of flying is to get a car across, to transport what you need to use on the other end. A commercial ferry which allows private people on board would work.

Comment: There are a number of people who have written a report of their trip on the ferry as a non-commercial basis: https://driveeurope.co.uk/2016/03/30/a9-update-france-biggest-dustiest-motorway-project/ http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/the-freight-escape-simon-calder-left-for-his-skiing-holiday-as-an-airline-passenger-but-came-home-as-1951914.html and this previous question:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52297/is-it-possible-to-travel-on-the-immingham-brevik-ferry-without-bringing-a-motor most of them are now a few years old though

Comment: @skifans,@Willeke it appears the ability to take private passengers has been withdrawn for some reason."private passengers
DFDS freight port of Immingham can accept commercial freight drivers with their loads. Due to UKBF port approval private passengers are not permitted to be carried through Immingham, this means that we can no longer accept leisure fare paying passengers on the freight routes through Immingham. Leisure passengers should refer to our passenger ferries section on the website for details on our passenger services."